# How should QLocalSocket/QDataStream be read to avoid deadlocks?

Tags: c++, qt, named-pipes, qlocalsocket

How should QLocalSocket/QDataStream be read?

I have a program that communicates with another via named pipes using `QLocalSocket` and `QDataStream`. The `recieveMessage()` slot below is connected to the `QLocalSocket`'s `readyRead()` signal.

```
void MySceneClient::receiveMessage()
{    
    qint32 msglength;
    (*m_stream) >> msglength;

    char* msgdata = new char[msglength];
    int read = 0;
    while (read < msglength) {
        read += m_stream->readRawData(&msgdata[read], msglength - read);
    }
    ...
}
```

I find that the application *sometimes* hangs on `readRawData()`. That is, it succesfully reads the 4 byte header, but then never returns from `readRawData()`.

If I add...

```
if (m_socket->bytesAvailable() < 5)
    return;
```

...to the start of this function, the application works fine (with the short test message).

I am guessing then (the documentation is very sparse) that there is some sort of deadlock occurring, and that I must use the `bytesAvailable()` signal to gradually build up the buffer rather than blocking.

**Why is this? And what is the correct approach to reading from QLocalSocket?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop blocks the event loop, so you will never get data if all did not arrive pn first read, is what causes your problem I think.

Correct approach is to use signals and slots, `readyRead`-signal here, and just read the available data in your slot, and if there's not enough, buffer it and return, and read more when you get the next signal.

*Be careful with this alternative approach:*  If you are absolutely sure all the data you expect is going to arrive promptly (perhaps not unreasonable with a local socket where you control both client and server), or if the whole thing is in a thread which doesn nothing else, then it may be ok to use `waitForReadyRead` method. But the event loop will remain blocked until data arrives, freezing GUI for example (if in GUI thread), and generally troublesome.

Comment: thanks, it didn't occur to me it was *my* loop blocking (even though I saw it spinning round in the debugger!) and not readRawData().